# Generating client events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I use this code for generating mouse click in Web browser:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element_id');
var o = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
o.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null);
element.dispatchEvent(o);
```

It works, but I cannot understand what does 6th - 9th (12, 345, 7, 220) arguments do? When I change it - it doesn't change anything. I find in [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.initMouseEvent)
that these arguments are `screenX` , `screenY`, `clientX` and `clientY` coordinates, but what does that mean?

Comment: It just specifies where on the page / screen the click event takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameters are added to the event that is created. When you originally receive a mouseclick event you too get the current screenX/Y and clientX/Y coordinates of the event in the event object. This way you can fill those parameters. If they are not used when processing the event those will have no effect at all.

Simply put those parameters show where on the screen (screenx/y) and where within the browser boundaries (clientx/y) the click happened.

You can read about the parameters here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.screenX

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.screenY

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.clientX

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.clientY

Comment: Is it mean that when i'm generating client event programming it doesn't do anything?

Comment: It will set the screen/client corrdinates within the event. So if you read those from the event handler the values you set on creation here will show up there again. It's like the user clicked on the same object on your page but while it was scrolled to another position or while the browser was on anohter position of the screen.